# How can I make exception handling for all existing SQL server 2005 Stored Procedures, view and functions?

Tags: sql-server-2005, exception

we have a portal that have SQL server 2005 database that contain about 1750 stored procedures , 250 view and 200 function and 95% of them not have handling exception in their code .. we search about any way that allow us making such a global exception handling in SQL that receive any exception happen in any SP,view or function and stored it in a table we made ..  is there something like this in SQL server 2005 or we must write exception handling code on each item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the same question in http://ask.sqlteam.com/questions/2745 and i have some information